# (elisp dash.el) help rewriting clunky code

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to create a composition in dash, that does the following
 - split into lines
 - remove empty lines
 - keep lines starting w/"N"
 - return filename extension

However the code below feels clunky - wondering if anyone could help
simplify/rewrite this.

```
(let ((line-sep "\\\n")
      (new-ind "^N ")
      (sample-output "
N /dir1/file1.el
N /dir1/file2.dot
  /dir1/file3.py
  /dir1/file4.sql"))
  (funcall
   (-compose
    (-partial '-map (lambda(x) (file-name-extension (nth 1 (split-string x)))))
    (-partial '-filter (-partial 'string-match-p new-ind)) ; keep lines starting w/"N"
    (-partial '-filter (lambda(x) (> (length x) 0))) ; remove empty lines
    (-partial (-flip 'split-string) line-sep)) ; split into lines
   sample-output))
```

Answer (score 0):

After fooling around with it, it looks like the compose pipeline only works well when all the functions take the same type of argument.. I rewrote it like so, and it seems like a better fit; would like to hear comments..

```
(let* ((line-sep "\\\n")
       (lexical-binding t)
       (new-ind "^\\s-*N ")
       (sample-output "
    N /dir1/file1.el
    N /dir1/file2.dot
      /dir1/file3.py
      /dir1/file4.sql")
       (lines (split-string sample-output "\\\n")))

  (-annotate
   'file-name-extension
   (-map
    (-compose
     (-partial 'nth 2)
     (-partial (-flip 'split-string) "\\s-+"))
    (--filter
     (string-match-p "^\\s-*N " it)
     lines))))
```

Comment: Let-binding lexical-binding as above doesn't do what you think: `lexical-binding` needs to be set *outside* of the code, usually in a file-local variable at the top of the file.

Comment: As much as I like Haskell or more generally higher-order functions, I can't recommend this kind of use of higher-order functions in Elisp: the Elisp interpreter&compiler is *really* not geared toward this kind of code, so the performance will suck.

Comment: @Stefan - fair point on the use of lexical binding.. it's a holdover from my trials, and doesn't add anything. On performance, wouldn't that then be a knock against using dash.el in general?